# Java null pointer exception in REST API

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, web-services

I am actually using postman to send login request to my REST API but it's giving me a `javaNullpointer` exception. It's because in model class one of my variables is not getting a value. `setPhone_Number()` function is not called in my model class. So the `phone_number` variable is empty.

Help is appreciated.

Here is my error screnshot [eclipse error for null pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNNB2.jpg)
 here is what i am sending through postman [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r1AP.jpg)

here is the login dao class.

```
 public class LoginDao {

 private String password;
 private String phone_number;


    public LoginDao(){
        phone_number = null;
        password = null;
    }

    public Response doLogin(login logg, String user_type) throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean userType = true;        
        //if userType is resource then boolean is false, if userType is user then boolean is true.
        //logg.setPhone_Number(phone_number);

        DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
        //Connection connection = dbConnection.getConnection();
        this.phone_number = logg.getPhone_Number();
        this.password = logg.getPassword();


        try{
            if(user_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rider")) {
                rs = dbConnection.runSql("select rider_id, phone_number, password from rider");
                userType = true;

            }
            else if(user_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Driver")) {
                rs = dbConnection.runSql("select driver_id, phone_number, password from driver");   
                userType = false;
            }

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(phone_number);
                System.out.println(rs.getString("phone_number"));
                System.out.println("user"+user_type);

                if((this.phone_number.equals(rs.getString("phone_number"))) && (this.password.equals(rs.getString("password")))){
```

Here is model class login

```
 public class login {

private String phone_number;
private String password;

public login(){

}

public String getPhone_Number() {

    System.out.println("getting "+phone_number);
    return phone_number;
}

public void setPhone_Number(String phone_number) {

    System.out.println("seting "+phone_number);
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {

    System.out.println("seting "+password);
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Here is loginResource.java

```
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;

 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

 import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

 import java.sql.SQLException;

  import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

  import io.github.yasirfaisal21.schoolvan.schoolvan.dao.LoginDao;
 import io.github.yasirfaisal21.schoolvan.schoolvan.model.login;

  @Path("login")


 public class loginResource {
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
public Response doLogin(login log,@QueryParam("user_type") String user_type ) 
        throws SQLException{


LoginDao loginDao = new LoginDao();
if(user_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rider"))
        return loginDao.doLogin(log,"Rider");
else
    return loginDao.doLogin(log,"Driver");
 }

}
```

Comment: In stack trace. it shows the error in `line number 52 in LoginDao`. Can you Please share the 52 number line from LoginDao?

Comment: it seems that you are not taking in `login log` param in `loginResource.doLogin`

Comment: As it is, the `login` constructor sets `phonenumber` to null. Also, `LoginDao`'s constructor sets `phonenumber` to null. they will remain null as long as you supply your own `login`, which i see you are trying to do in `loginResource`. Could you post the request headers?

Comment: @EmptyBrain this is line 52  
 if((this.phone_number.equals(rs.getString("phone_number"))) && (this.password.equals(rs.getString("password")))){

Comment: @Fabulous sir as u can see in first screenshot that setting abc123 is called which means password is set but setPhone_Number() function is not called.

Comment: @Fabulous request header can be found in screenshot named as postman in starting

Comment: `LoginDao` and `Login` are different. In `LoginDao` you have put `null`. That is what is used when you call `doLogin`. You are not using `Login` object, so whatever value goes into `Login` is not used as you are calling `doLogin` of `loginDao`

Comment: Please share the form. check the log variable..`doLogin(login log,@QueryParam("user_type") String user_type ) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `login.java` class, replace: 
`private String phone_number;` 
 with 
`private String phoneNumber;`

and update its getters and setters according like so:

```
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: Still same problem. Actually my setPoneNumber function is not being called, i check it by printing values. Setpassword function is working correctly :(

Comment: Have you updated the json body in postman as well? Change phone_number to phoneNumber and let me know if setter is being called or not.

Answer (score 0):

In `loginResource.java`, the line

`LoginDao loginDao = new LoginDao();`

calls this method in `LoginDao`:

```
public LoginDao(){
        phone_number = null;
        password = null;
    }
```

where you have explicitly set `phone_number = null`

now on Line 52 of `LoginDao`

```
if((this.phone_number.equals(rs.getString("phone_number"))) && (this.password.equals(rs.getString("password"))))
```

`this.phone_number` corresponds to the `LoginDao` object most recently constructed, which has `phone_number` set to null. Even before values can be compared with `rs`, the `equals` function fails and you get a `null pointer` exception.

You should instead take in the values `phone_number` and `password` from the request. Try creating a parametrized constructor and assigning them the values you pass, like so:

```
public LoginDao(String number, String password){
         this.phone_number = number;
         this.password = password;
}
```

and calling it from `loginResource` like so:

```
if(user_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rider"))
        return new loginDao(number,password).doLogin(log,"Rider");
else
    return new loginDao(number,password).doLogin(log,"Driver");
 }
```

**Alternatively,** I think you are trying to save parameters into `Login` object, but you haven't done that anywhere in `loginResource`. You should change your constructor in `loginDao` to

```
public loginDao() { }
```

and write the following in `loginResource` :

```
Login login = new Login();
if(user_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rider")){
       login.setPhone_number("your phone number from request");
        return loginDao.doLogin(log,"Rider");
 }
else
  {
   login.setPhone_number("your phone number from request");
  return loginDao.doLogin(log,"Driver");
 }
```